# populate_io_cache_on_flush is not a column defined in this metadata

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

While connecting to Cassandra 1.2.1 using Data-stax Java driver version 1.0.2, I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: populate_io_cache_on_flush is not a column defined in this metadata
at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.getIdx(ColumnDefinitions.java:268)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Row.isNull(Row.java:84)
at com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata$Options.<init>(TableMetadata.java:440)
at com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata.build(TableMetadata.java:107)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata.buildTableMetadata(Metadata.java:124)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata.rebuildSchema(Metadata.java:88)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:265)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:220)
```

at below line:

```
            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build();
```

I tried deleted folder \var\lib\cassandra and then restart the cassandra server too which means there is no previous data. The server starts without any error but I am still getting the above error when I am trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohk. Just discovered that it went away when I use latest version of Cassandra(1.2.8). So it might be because of version incompatibility.

Comment: hmm ... and how do we solve this? I mean this is more an explanation then a solution.

Comment: so the solution is to use the same client library than the server is. i.e. after a ubuntu updates the server (what happened today) all your client programs have to upgrade the driver too.