# Which version of cqlsh is compatible with Cassandra 2.1.9?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cqlsh, nosql

I am facing the same problem that is mentioned in the question [populate_io_cache_on_flush is not a column defined in this metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505619/populate-io-cache-on-flush-is-not-a-column-defined-in-this-metadata).

As per the solution specified by [KIC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298461/kic) in the 2nd comment on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505805/3515086) , i need to

*"Use the same client library than the server is. i.e. after a ubuntu updates the server (what happened today) all your client programs have to upgrade the driver too."*

I am using Cassandra 2.1.9. and cqlsh 5.0.1 .

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.9 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

Which version of cqlsh should i be using to sort out my problem?

### ----

**Edit(Solved):** I got this problem solved by using the client library version 2.1.3.

My maven dependency now looks like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for your help fellas.

Comment: Having the exact same issue now. The problem, from what I understand, is the "Native protocol version", not necessarily the cqlsh version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an ultra-ugly, but quick fix:

Find the `cqlsh.py` file in your file system, and change `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` to 3:

```
...
DEFAULT_CQLVER = '3.3.0'
DEFAULT_PROTOCOL_VERSION = 3
DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 5
...
```

On my system (Mac OS X installed via `homebrew`) this file was in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.2.0/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py
```

The rather odd thing is that you can't override this variable via the command-line..

You may also have to change the actual CQL version like so:

```
cqlsh 127.0.0.1 --cqlversion=3.2.0
```

Temporary fix to an ultra-annoying problem..

Comment: after losing several hours online looking for solution this worked for me. Thank you

Comment: The only thing I've found that works. Thanks! I sure wish this could be specified from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. The problem has been fixed upstream: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13307 but is not yet in a release. You can, however, check out cassandra repo and build it yourself. Or just install the dependencies with pip and run the `cqlsh` script from the cassandra checkout.